# How to access inner fields having filtered on parent fields in mongoDB in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection of documents with this structure in mongoDB:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("50f970caaa070bb8150000ae"),
    nombre: "Argentina",
    poblacion: 1000,
    provincias: [
        {
            nombre: "Buenos Aires",
            gobernador: "Jorge Luis",
            cantMedicos: 2,
            _id: ObjectId("50f970caaa070bb8150000a9")
        },
        {
            nombre: "Catamarca",
            gobernador: "Rodrigo Neira",
            cantMedicos: 5,
            _id: ObjectId("50f970caaa070bb8150000aa")
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to print the field "gobernador" from all "provincias" whose parent's "nombre" is equals to "Argentina".
But i can't find the way to achieve this in PHP.

Comment: You *can't find a way*? [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: `$doc['provincias']['gobernador']` will do it, MongoDB returns the root document structure even if you tell it not to, it just fails to return the top level fields.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be selecting all documents with `{ nombre: "Argentina" }` via [MongoCollection::find()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php). That should return an iterable [MongoCursor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php) and allow you to access all matched documents.

Each document will be an array, so you can access the appropriate field just as Sammaye mentioned in the comment above.

You also have the option of having `find()` [project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#projection) specific fields in the matching documents, which is helpful if your documents are very large and you'd like to reduce (a) the amount of data passed from MongoDB to the driver and/or (b) the amount of memory consumed to work with returned documents. Query projections are controlled via the second parameter to `MongoCollection::find()` and are documented in the aforementioned link.